# Testng - Update status of TesScript if it pass in second or third Re Run

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

We are re running failed tests using IRetryAnalyzer Class but if it got passed in second or third run the test case count is showing as 3 instead of one. I mean if it is passed in third attempt the total test case count showing as three instead of one.

If it reran 3 times and if it got passed in third time the result shown like below
Total run:1  failed:0  skipped:0 in testng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is expected behavior. Each retry attempt is counted as a different test run.

But if you want to update failed and skipped counts. You can try below snippet

```
public class RetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {
    private int count = 0;
    private static final int MAX_RETRY_COUNT = 3;
    private int failedCount = 0;
    private int skippedCount = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        if (count < MAX_RETRY_COUNT) {
            count++;
            if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
                failedCount++;
            } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
                skippedCount++;
            }
            return true;
        }
        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
            result.setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int getFailedCount() {
        return failedCount;
    }

    public int getSkippedCount() {
        return skippedCount;
    }
}
```